# String encryption only with numbers?

Tags: string, security, encryption, primes

Suppose your bank clerk gives you an arbitrary password such as `hel34/hjal0@#` and you cannot remember it without writing it to a paper. Dilemma: you never write passwords to paper. So you try to invent an encryption, one-to-one map, where you write only a key to a paper, only numbers, and leave the rest junk to your server. Of course, the password can consist of arbitrary things.

[mvds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567176/0-9a-za-z-string-expressed-with-primes-or-prime-factorization-style-way-to-bre/4567222#4567222) has the correct idea, to change the base. [Eugene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567176/string-encryption-only-with-numbers/4573442#4573442) noticed an error, so the one-to-one-map should be like:

```
prime1*prime2*...*primeN <----- encoding -------> String
```

Comment: I think you need to give us some examples. I've no idea what you want here.

Comment: Damn, I thought I got it but 1a2 == 11412 doesn't make sense to me...

Comment: oh it does, `'a' == 0141`... This is not a good idea, since different input strings could lead to the same "alphs to oct" string. 14a == "14141" == a41. So you lose information in encoding.

Comment: @HH converting base: start from the right and add each digit, multiplied by base^N.

Comment: Are you hashing or encrypting?

Comment: @Donal Fellows: dunno, I want to get a short sequence of numbers by which I get long strings back. mvds has the idea, now the implementation missing, hence in SO

Comment: @HH: The difference is that in hashing you're going one-way (useful for things like integrity checking) whereas in encrypting you need to be able to reverse it (provided you have a decryption key). The difference matters because with hashing you use many-to-one maps, whereas with encrypting you use one-to-one maps. At first glance, your scheme appears to be a many-to-one map, so I was wondering if this was intentional or an accident. :-)

Comment: @Donal Fellows: I meant one-to-one map i.e. encryption because I want to be able to reverse it.

Comment: @HH: OK, thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I really understand your problem, but you could see your input as a base-62 number (26+26+10), which you could read in as an integer, and then process it any way you like. Then convert the result back to your custom base-62 format.

So as an example, your digit range is `[0-9a-zA-Z]` so `0` = 0 decimal and `Z` = 61 decimal, and `10` would be 62 decimal.

Then `9aZ` would be 9*62*62 + 10*62 + 61 = 35277 decimal, which has prime factors 3 * 11 * 1069.

Converting them back would lead to: `9aZ = 3 * b * hg`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your numeric code can't be shorter, than the password: shorter password reduces protection strength. So you need to keep the password either intact (and just encode it) or make it even longer.

When talking about encoding, you can use BASE10 or BASE16 encoding. With Base16 encoding you have 2 characters per original character (if we stay within ASCII charset), with Base10 encoding the length would vary, and to ensure correct decoding you would end up using 3 characters per original ASCII character.